# Fahrenheit / Celsius temperature converter - follow-up

Tags: beginner, bash, shell, unit-conversion

This is an updated version of the script [Fahrenheit / Celsius temperature converter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140515/fahrenheit-celsius-temperature-converter). I have changed the script to be non-interactive, using positional parameters instead of asking for user input once the script is running. In my testing of the script, everything seems to work as it should. But I am quite new to using positional parameters and I'm wondering if this is the best way of using them or if there might be a more streamlined approach.

`help shift` says:

> ```
> shift: shift [n]
>     Shift positional parameters.
>
>     Rename the positional parameters $N+1,$N+2 ... to $1,$2 ...  If N is
>     not given, it is assumed to be 1.
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Returns success unless N is negative or greater than $#.
> ```

Which leaves me still uncertain as to what that means exactly or how to implement it correctly. The script seems to work but I'd like to know if I could / should do anything differently.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo -e "usage: temp [-f][-c]|[number]|[-h]\nExample:\n\ttemp -f 54\n\ttemp -c 24.5\n"
}
re='^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    usage
    exit 1
elif [[ ! "$2" =~ $re ]]; then
    usage
    exit 1
elif [[ "$3" != "" ]]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -f )    shift
                RES="$(echo "scale=2; (${1}-32)*5/9" | bc -q -l; printf "\b˚C")"
                echo "${1}˚F = "${RES}
                exit
                ;;

        -c )    shift
                RES="$(echo "scale=2; ${1}*9/5+32" | bc -q -l; printf "\b˚F")" 
                echo "${1}˚C = "${RES}
                exit
                ;;

        -h )    usage
                exit
                ;;

        * )     usage
                exit 1
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shift` shifts the command line argument list by `n`, or by 1 if `n` is unspecified.
For example, given `-c 25`, the value of `$1` is `-c`.
After you call `shift` without parameters,
it shifts the parameters by 1, so `$1` becomes `25`.
You used it correctly.

#### Use here-documents

This is hard to read:

> ```
> echo -e "usage: temp [-f][-c]|[number]|[-h]\nExample:\n\ttemp -f 54\n\ttemp -c 24.5\n"
> ```

Using a here-document, it becomes much easier to read:

```
usage() {
    cat << EOF
usage: temp [-f][-c]|[number]|[-h]
Example:
    temp -f 54
    temp -c 24.5
EOF
}
```

#### Simplify conditions

This can be written slightly simpler:

> ```
> if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
> ```

Like this:

```
if [ ! "$1" ]; then
```

This can be written much simpler:

> ```
> elif [[ "$3" != "" ]]; then
>     usage
>     exit 1
> fi
> while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
> ```

Like this:

```
elif [[ "$3" ]]; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi
while [ "$1" ]; do
```

#### Simplify the `bc` calls

These statements are unnecessarily complicated:

> ```
> -f )    shift
>         RES="$(echo "scale=2; (${1}-32)*5/9" | bc -q -l; printf "\b˚C")"
>         echo "${1}˚F = "${RES}
>         exit
>         ;;
>
> -c )    shift
>         RES="$(echo "scale=2; ${1}*9/5+32" | bc -q -l; printf "\b˚F")" 
>         echo "${1}˚C = "${RES}
>         exit
>         ;;
> ```

That is:

- Doing part of the output formatting when you create `RES` and the other part when you `echo` it is confusing, it would be better to separate
- Printing a backspace character becomes unnecessary when you separate the calculation and display formatting of `RES`
- The quoting around `$(...)` is unnecessary
- Instead of `echo`-ing the command for `bc`, a here-string would be better

Like this:

```
RES=$(bc -q <<< "scale=2; ${1}*9/5+32")
echo "${1}˚C = ${RES}˚F"
```

Notice how the assignment of `RES` has only calculation logic, no display logic. All the display logic is on the next line.
The result is cleaner and shorter.